# Get .html() with jquery except content of child

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Somewhat cryptic topic but this is what I want to do...

Say I got a list with the following HTML

```
<ul> 
    <li> I want to be selected <span class="skipme">but I rather not</span> </li>
</ul>
```

Now I want to get all html/text inside `<li>` except contents from children that has the identifier `.skipme`.

How do I achieve this?

I've been playing around with the not selector without any luck. e.g.

```
var MyHtml = $('ul li').not('skipme').html();
console.log(MyHtml)
```

prints `I want to be selected <span class="skipme">but I rather not</span>` instead of `I want to be selected` that is what I want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

```
$("ul li").clone().children().remove().end().text();
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ugwNN/)**

For Removing elements with certain class:

```
$("ul li").clone().children('.skipme').remove().end().text();   
                               ^
                               |____ add selector here
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/A3Sde/)**

Comment: Dangit, you JUST beat me to it.

Comment: God bless john resig... :)

Comment: Thanks, but this will only remove all children right? I only want to remove those with the class skipme. Not desired behavior -> http://jsfiddle.net/JLhyW/

Comment: There you go http://jsfiddle.net/A3Sde/.... pass the selector `.skipme` in `children()` method.

Answer (score 0):

You can just do this:

```
var text = $('ul li')[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/n9Bww/)**

Comment: Good if you want to only select the first part, otherwise [***not***](http://jsfiddle.net/MD96X/)

Answer (score 0):

I presume you have a list of items, so I would loop through like this:

```
$('ul li').each(function(i) {
    var replacedText = $(this).text().replace($(this).find('.skipme').text(), '');
    // console.log(replacedText);
});
```

Answer (score -2):

You can try this using just jquery selectors

```
$('ul li').before($('.skipme')).html();
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7nNF7/1/)

Comment: This actually modifies the DOM.